# Proving a sharp maximum identity for some relatively prime odd integers

Tags: calculus, number-theory, proof-writing, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Let $p, q$ and $r$ be relatively prime **odd** positive integers satisfying $$pq + pr - qr = 1$$ and $$1<p<q<r.$$

Define $$f(a,n)= -(q + r)a^2 + 4aqn - 4(q - p)n^2 - 4n$$ where $-p \leq a \leq p+2$ and $1 \leq n \leq r-1$.

Under these conditions, can we prove that

$$\mathrm max \{ f(a,n) \} =f(1,1)$$

Or can one produce a *counterexample*?

**For example**, I proved the above idendity for triplets $$(p,q,r)=(2k+1,4k+1,4k+3)$$ and $$(p,q,r)=(4k+3,6k+5,12k+7)$$ by showing $$-f(a,n) + f(1,1) \geq 0$$ with the help of basic number theoretic arguments.

Any contribution (proof suggestion or a counterexample) will make me extremely happy...

**EDIT**

The above numbers have meaning in topology. For example, consider [Pretzel knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel_link) $K(-p,q,r)$ where $p, q$ and $r$ are relatively prime odd positive integers satisfying $$pq + pr - qr = 1.$$

Then the [Alexander polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_polynomial) associated to these knots is $1$, i.e,. $$\Delta_K(K(-p,q,r))=1,$$ see pg. 66, Example 6.9, **W. B. Raymond Lickorish - An Introduction to Knot Theory**.

Following [Freedman](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214437136)'s excellent paper, one can conclude that $K(-p,q,r)$ are [topologically slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slice_knot).

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But, this problem is really far from the initial point and the terminal argument is just connected with the initial one only in a combinatorial sense (some matrix multiplications, determinants, etc.). In any case, I'll try my best along your right wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demanding $n \geq 1$ cuts out a few counterexamples...

```
   WOW     p 7     q  9     r  31  a  0   n  1    1_1: -16  f  -12
   WOW     p 7     q  9     r  31  a  1   n  2    1_1: -16  f  -8
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  0   n  1    1_1: -28  f  -12
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  1   n  2    1_1: -28  f  -12
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  1   n  3    1_1: -28  f  -12
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  2   n  5    1_1: -28  f  -20
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  2   n  6    1_1: -28  f  -24
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  0   n  1    1_1: -44  f  -12
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  0   n  2    1_1: -44  f  -40
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  1   n  2    1_1: -44  f  -20
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  1   n  3    1_1: -44  f  -12
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  1   n  4    1_1: -44  f  -20
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  2   n  5    1_1: -44  f  -36
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  2   n  6    1_1: -44  f  -24
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  2   n  7    1_1: -44  f  -28
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  3   n  9    1_1: -44  f  -36
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  3   n  10    1_1: -44  f  -36
   WOW     p 11     q  15     r  41  a  1   n  2    1_1: -16  f  -8
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  0   n  1    1_1: -64  f  -12
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  0   n  2    1_1: -64  f  -40
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  1   n  2    1_1: -64  f  -32
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  1   n  3    1_1: -64  f  -16
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  1   n  4    1_1: -64  f  -16
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  1   n  5    1_1: -64  f  -32
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  2   n  6    1_1: -64  f  -40
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  2   n  7    1_1: -64  f  -28
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  2   n  8    1_1: -64  f  -32
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  2   n  9    1_1: -64  f  -52
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  3   n  10    1_1: -64  f  -48
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  3   n  11    1_1: -64  f  -40
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  3   n  12    1_1: -64  f  -48
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  4   n  14    1_1: -64  f  -56
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: How shall I read numbers after the valuation of r?

Comment: your $a$ and $n$ are next. The symbol 1_1 is followed by $f(1,1)$ and the final number, after the letter $f,$ is $f(a,n)$ for the specified $a,n$ ordered pair, that is larger than $f(1,1),$ where typically both are negative. Check a few of the lines with small $(p,q,r)$ Apparently with $(p,q,r) = (7,9,31)$ both $f(0,1) > f(1,1)$ and $f(1,2) > f(1,1)$

Comment: If it is ok with you, can you share your code with me in order to improve the conjecture?

Comment: @ToposLogos posted as separate answer. Should not be difficult to adapt it for any language you know.

Answer (score 0):

From $pq = 1 + r(q-p)$ we find that $q > p$ unless both are $1.$

with $p=q=1,$ odd positive $r,$ the value 
$$ f(0,0) > f(1,1) $$

Comment: I forgot the assumption $1<p<q<r$. Thanks for your attention, I edited.

Comment: @ToposLogos we also get $f(0,0) > f(1,1)$ when $(p,q,r) = (3,5,7).$ In this case, $a-n$ is a factor of the quadratic part of $f,$ so when $a=n$ you are left with $f=-4n$

Answer (score 0):

your conjecture needs work

```
   WOW     p 3     q  5     r  7  a  0   n  0 1_1 -4  f  0
   WOW     p 5     q  7     r  17  a  0   n  0 1_1 -8  f  0
   WOW     p 5     q  9     r  11  a  0   n  0 1_1 -4  f  0
   WOW     p 7     q  9     r  31  a  0   n  0 1_1 -16  f  0
   WOW     p 7     q  9     r  31  a  0   n  1 1_1 -16  f  -12
   WOW     p 7     q  9     r  31  a  1   n  2 1_1 -16  f  -8
   WOW     p 7     q  11     r  19  a  0   n  0 1_1 -6  f  0
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  0   n  0 1_1 -28  f  0
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  0   n  1 1_1 -28  f  -12
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  1   n  2 1_1 -28  f  -12
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  1   n  3 1_1 -28  f  -12
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  2   n  5 1_1 -28  f  -20
   WOW     p 9     q  11     r  49  a  2   n  6 1_1 -28  f  -24
   WOW     p 7     q  13     r  15  a  0   n  0 1_1 -4  f  0
   WOW     p 9     q  13     r  29  a  0   n  0 1_1 -10  f  0
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  0   n  0 1_1 -44  f  0
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  0   n  1 1_1 -44  f  -12
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  0   n  2 1_1 -44  f  -40
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  1   n  2 1_1 -44  f  -20
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  1   n  3 1_1 -44  f  -12
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  1   n  4 1_1 -44  f  -20
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  2   n  5 1_1 -44  f  -36
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  2   n  6 1_1 -44  f  -24
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  2   n  7 1_1 -44  f  -28
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  3   n  9 1_1 -44  f  -36
   WOW     p 11     q  13     r  71  a  3   n  10 1_1 -44  f  -36
   WOW     p 11     q  15     r  41  a  0   n  0 1_1 -16  f  0
   WOW     p 11     q  15     r  41  a  1   n  2 1_1 -16  f  -8
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  0   n  0 1_1 -64  f  0
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  0   n  1 1_1 -64  f  -12
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  0   n  2 1_1 -64  f  -40
   WOW     p 13     q  15     r  97  a  1   n  2 1_1 -64  f  -32
```

Comment: We have to assume $n \geq 1$...

Answer (score 0):

```
// language is called C++   
//  anything after a // sign is ignored by the computer

int main()
{
 //  system("date");

int bound = 135;

int goon = 1;

for(int q = 3; goon && q < bound; q += 2){
for(int p = 1; goon && p < q; p += 2 ){

  if( (p*q - 1) % (q-p) == 0 )
  {
    int r =  (p*q - 1) / (q-p) ;
    if( r % 2 == 1 && r > q)
    {
 //     cout << " p " << p <<  "     q  " << q << "     r  " << r ;
   //   if( twogcd(p,q) > 1 || twogcd(q,r) > 1 || twogcd(r,p) > 1 ) cout << "  pair ";
   //   cout << endl; 

      int a = 1;
      int n = 1;


      int remember = -(q+r) * a * a + 4*q*a*n - 4*(q-p)*n*n - 4*n;

      for(a = -p; goon && a <= p+2; ++a){
      for(n = 1; goon && n <= r-1; ++n){

       int f = -(q+r) * a * a + 4*q*a*n - 4*(q-p)*n*n - 4*n;
        if ( f > remember)
        {
          cout << "   WOW    " ;
       //    goon = 0;
          cout << " p " << p <<  "     q  " << q << "     r  " << r << "  a  " << a << "   n  "   << n << "    1_1: " << remember << "  f  "  << f << endl ;

        } // if f

      }}  // a n




    } // if r odd 
  } // if %


}} // p q

 // system("date");
   cout << endl << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=